# How to force the MongoDB to save the text index in SSD, Not in RAM

Tags: mongodb

My server just has 2G RAM, and I have 100G text and many other key fields which must be indexed to RAM,  full text search is not my key function, I hope the mongoDB don't load the text index to RAM. How to config the server.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB implements caching by storing everything in memory-mapped files. This is a feature which is managed by your operating system, not by MongoDB.

Most operating systems are quite smart at detecting which memory-mapped files are accessed how often. When your text index is used much less frequently than other data, it will usually be the first to be suspended to hard drive.